Vishnusahasranama 9-syllable line
The viSNusahasranAma from the mahAbhArata follows the epic anuSTubh chandas as do most classical shlokas today. The anuSTubh chandas has shlokas follow a 4x8 pattern, with 4 parts of 8 syllables each. However, the 54th shloka of the viSNusahasranAma breaks this rule.
|1| sOmapO'mRtapaH sOmaH 
|2| purujitpurusattamaH 
|3| vinayO'jayaH satyasandhO 
|4| dAshArhaH sAttvatAM patiH
The 3rd line clearly has 9 syllables. Why is this?
